# SQL Server: Duplicate columns in joined table, but distinct row info

Tags: sql-server

So I have joined two tables to identify claims and their corresponding reversals if there are any.
The following is a simplified explanation as to what I have done: Join where MbrNo is the same in both tables, and where Amount=-Amount. So now I have an output table contians duplicate column names:

```
MbrNo | ClaimType | Amount | MbrNo | ClaimType | Amount
xyz   | Medicine  | R 300  | xyz   | Reversal  | - R300
```

I can not input this in a table as column names are not unique.
But I would like to
1. Format this table to look as follows

```
MbrNo | ClaimType | Amount 
xyz | Medicine  | R 300 
xyz   | Reversal  | - R300
```

```
with t as 
(   
    select *,
    count(*) over(partition by [MbrNo], [DepNo], [PracticeNo], [DisciplineCd], [ServiceDt],[PayAmt]) as rownum
    from Claims
)
Select * from 
(Select * from t where PayAmt<0) a
left outer join 
(Select * from t where PayAmt>0) b
on a.[MbrNo]=b.[MbrNo]
and a.[DepNo]=b.[DepNo]
and a.[PracticeNo]=b.[PracticeNo]
and a.[DisciplineCd]=b.[DisciplineCd]
and a.[ServiceDt]=b.[ServiceDt]
and a.[PayAmt]=-b.[PayAmt]
```

Basically I want to put the 2nd table in the joined table underneath the first table.

Please help:(

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your requirements correctly then I think you want the [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) operator. See if this gets you going in the right direction.

```
with t as 
(    
    select *,
    count(*) over(partition by [MbrNo], [DepNo], [PracticeNo], [DisciplineCd], [ServiceDt],[PayAmt]) as rownum
    from Claims
)
Select t.* from t where PayAmt < 0
union all
select b.* from
(Select * from t where PayAmt < 0) a
inner join 
(Select * from t where PayAmt > 0) b
on a.[MbrNo] = b.[MbrNo]
and a.[DepNo] = b.[DepNo]
and a.[PracticeNo] = b.[PracticeNo]
and a.[DisciplineCd] = b.[DisciplineCd]
and a.[ServiceDt] = b.[ServiceDt]
and a.[PayAmt] = -b.[PayAmt]
```

Comment: If this answer has helped you then please help me and click the green tick :)